# Can we use a single frame to create the following effect?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

I want to create a slide to show how the clipping works as shown in the following animation.

[image]

I used two frames, the last frame is needed because I want to hide the unwanted (trimmed) parts of cropped areas of the previous slides. I want to avoid using two frames and repeating the codes.

Can we force `beamer` to delay the clipping code and hiding the previous painting? I am new to `beamer`, only knows `\pause`. :-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)\pause
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)\pause
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)\pause
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)  
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)
        \endpsclip
    \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\only` or `\onslide`; an example with `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \only<5>{\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}}
        \only<1->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)}
        \only<2->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)}
        \only<3->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \only<4->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)}
       \only<5>{\endpsclip}
     \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After getting a multipe-page PDF,  we can also make use of it to create a PDF animation, a GIF animation and PNG images.  TeX the following with `pdflatex --shell-escape`. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) must be installed in your computer.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \only<5>{\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}}
        \only<1->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)}
        \only<2->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)}
        \only<3->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \only<4->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)}
       \only<5>{\endpsclip}
     \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

% create PDF
\immediate\write18{latex dummy}
\immediate\write18{dvips dummy}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps}

% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 100 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove dummy.pdf \jobname.gif}

% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha remove dummy.pdf \jobname-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother

% create PDF animation
\begin{preview}
    \animategraphics[controls]{2}{dummy}{}{}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HiggsBoson thank you very much! Animation added!

Comment: For those who want to make use of the produced multiple-page PDF to create a PDF animation, a GIF animation and PNG images, please see the last edit.

Comment: Which is the most appropriate among `\uncover`, `\only`, `\onslide`, etc for  my problem above?

Comment: Why cannot your first code be compiled now while it worked several times ago?

Answer (score 7):

You could use TikZ, which is reasonably well integrated with Beamer already, and do something like:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip<5> (3,3) circle (3);
    \node [coordinate] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node [coordinate] (B) at (6,0) {};
    \node [coordinate] (C) at (6,6) {};
    \node [coordinate] (D) at (0,6) {};
    \node [coordinate] (P) at (1,1) {};
    \node [coordinate] (Q) at (5,1) {};
    \node [coordinate] (R) at (3,5) {};
    \fill<1-> [red] (A) -- (B) -- (Q) -- (P) -- cycle;
    \fill<2-> [green] (B) -- (C) -- (R) -- (Q) -- cycle;
    \fill<3-> [blue] (C) -- (D) -- (R) -- cycle;
    \fill<4-> [yellow] (D) -- (A) -- (P) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}
```

Result: 
[image: Solution with Beamer/TikZ]

Comment: The first slide is wrong; the red trapezoid "jumps".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The first canvas might have different dimension as TikZ provides the smallest but enough canvas automatically. Specifying the canvas dimension in advance will solve this issue.