# Is it possible to fill the complement of (A union B union C) with a solid color but the remaining regions remain transparent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Please ignore the binary numbers.

[image]

Without finding the intersection points in advance, is it possible to fill the complement of (A union B union C) with a solid color but the remaining regions remain transparent?

Comment: You have 8 regions and you can draw each region seperately as a closed path. So a macro can receive 8 bit number and pass `fill=blue` option to the path if it's 1 or 0 at the specific digit.

Comment: @percusse: How can you get the 8 regions without finding the intersection points in advance? :-)

Comment: Using geometry is one option (assuming that the circles are the same for all three and have predefined coordinates).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the approach described in [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={(current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}
]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

\draw [gray!20, ultra thick] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path  [clip] (90:0.7cm) circle [radius=1cm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (-30:0.7cm) circle [radius=1cm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (210:0.7cm) circle [radius=1cm] [reverseclip];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\fill [orange] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't known whether or not PSTricks has reverse clip.

Comment: I see you have defined a path around the whole page, can I use this path to fill the page with orange?

Comment: @qed: Sure. You can use `\fill [orange] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);`. Note that you need to have the options `remember picture, overlay` in your `tikzpicture` options, and you need to compile the document twice.

Comment: why is it necessary to remember the position of current picture in this case? And what is the difference between current page and current picture?

Comment: @qed: Take a look at section 16.13.2 "Referencing the Current Page Node" in the PGF manual.

Answer (score 7):

needs the latest `pstricks.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/ available on CTAN in a few days

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)\psgrid[gridlabels=0pt]
  \pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
  \pspolygon(-2,-2)(-2,2)(2,2)(2,-2)
  \moveto(0.7;90)\rmoveto(1,0)\pscircle(0.7;90){1}
  \moveto(0.7;-30)\rmoveto(1,0)\pscircle(0.7;-30){1}
  \moveto(0.7;210)\rmoveto(1,0)\pscircle(0.7;210){1}
  \closepath
  \code{eoclip}
  \pspolygon(-2,-2)(-2,2)(2,2)(2,-2)
  \fill[fillcolor=blue!60,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

but there are still some small lines for the circles:

[image]

Comment: Can PSTricks have reverse clip feature as Tikz?

Comment: sure, needs only one who implements it ...

Comment: I have not seen your PSTricks book because it is not available on the bookstore. Amazon.com also does not provide us with its table of contents. My question: what is the difference between the PSTricks package manuals and your PSTricks book? I am interested to know the details about PSTricks programming for hackers only (TVZ's manual on printed page number 38) and creating low/high level objects (TVZ's manual on printed page number 163-). Are both these topics elaborated in your PSTricks book?

Comment: see http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Books/

Comment: How to completely remove the unwanted thin but visible paths?