# TikZ clip shapes using several (built in) shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I'm looking for a way to draw one image composed of a union of multiple cloud shapes. The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\CloudDist}{1.8}

    \tikzstyle {cloudkeys} = [cloud puffs=30, cloud puff arc=150, aspect=1.25, inner sep=0.7cm,] 
    \tikzstyle {mycloud}   = [draw, cloud, cloudkeys, fill=blue!25, nearly opaque] 

    \coordinate (cloud 0);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 0] (cloud 1);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 1] (cloud 2);

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2} {
        \node [mycloud] at (cloud \x) (local map cloud shape \x) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this figure:

[image: WME Result]

but the desired result is something like this one:

[image]

I found some answers that *almost* showed me how to do it.

- Answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/tikz-clip-shapes-with-another-built-in-shape) shows how to clip shapes with another (single) shape;
- Answers in two other questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67403/is-it-possible-to-fill-the-complement-of-a-union-b-union-c-with-a-solid-color) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz)) shows how to invert a clip selection using basic shapes or paths.

I think what want to do can be achieved with a mix of these answers, but I couldn't do it myself. I would appreciate if someone can show me how to draw this figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use clipping, but the other solution is simpler.  Note that the nodes anchors do not form a rectangle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\CloudDist}{1.8}

    \tikzstyle {cloudkeys} = [cloud puffs=30, cloud puff arc=150, aspect=1.25, inner sep=0.7cm,] 
    \tikzstyle {mycloud}   = [draw, cloud, cloudkeys, fill=blue!25, nearly opaque] 

    \coordinate (cloud 0);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 0] (cloud 1);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 1] (cloud 2);

    \path (cloud 0) -- (cloud 1) coordinate[midway] (cloud edge 1);
    \path (cloud 1) -- (cloud 2) coordinate[midway] (cloud edge 2);

    \begin{scope}
      \node[cloud, cloudkeys,outer sep=2pt] (temp) at (cloud 0) {};% invisible, used for clip rectangle
      \clip (temp.south -| temp.west) rectangle (temp.north -| cloud edge 1);
      \node [mycloud] at (cloud 0) (local map cloud shape 0) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[cloud, cloudkeys,outer sep=2pt] (temp) at (cloud 1) {};% invisible, used for clip rectangle
      \clip (temp.south -| cloud edge 1) rectangle (temp.north -| cloud edge 2);
      \node [mycloud] at (cloud 1) (local map cloud shape 1) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[cloud, cloudkeys,outer sep=2pt] (temp) at (cloud 2) {};% invisible, used for clip rectangle
      \clip (temp.south -| cloud edge 2) rectangle (temp.north -| temp.east);
      \node [mycloud] at (cloud 2) (local map cloud shape 2) {};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is way more simpler than what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

No clipping is needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\CloudDist}{1.8}

    \tikzstyle {cloudkeys} = [cloud puffs=30, cloud puff arc=150, aspect=1.25, inner sep=0.7cm,] 
    \tikzstyle {mycloud1}   = [draw, cloud, cloudkeys, fill=blue!25]
    \tikzstyle {mycloud2}   = [      cloud, cloudkeys, fill=blue!25]

    \coordinate (cloud 0);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 0] (cloud 1);
    \coordinate [right=\CloudDist cm of cloud 1] (cloud 2);

\begin{scope}[transparency group,nearly opaque]
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2} {
        \node [mycloud1] at (cloud \x) (local map cloud shape \x) {};
    }
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2} {
        \node [mycloud2] at (cloud \x) (local map cloud shape \x) {};
    }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I really like your solution, but I have some problems using it in my document. In fact, my MWE is a simple version of a more complex picture. If I adapt the complex figure to use your solution, the cloud lines gets too thin, almost fading. The weird thing is that if I compile it as a standealone picture I get the desired result, but not when it is in the document. So for now I'm accepting the answer of @John Kormylo as the right answer, just because it worked in my document, although I find yours more elegant.