# How to draw A ⊕ B ⊕ C as a Venn diagram?

Tags: color, pstricks

> **This question led to a new package:**
>
> **[`pst-venn`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-venn?lang=en)**

You see my code and please answer my two questions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathptmx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(8,8)%[linestyle=none]
  \psclip{% 
        \pscircle(0,0){3}
        \pscircle(4,0){3} }
        \pscircle[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid](2,3){3}        
  \endpsclip
 \pscircle(0,0){3}
 \pscircle(4,0){3}
 \pscircle(2,3){3}
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

The output picture:

[image]

Picture 1:

[image]

Its code (use Ti*k*Z):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (3) (4,0) circle (3) (2,3) circle (3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My questions:

- How to make my picture like Picture 1? Truly I don't know how to fill color to it.
- (*After completing the previous question*) Do you see the Ti*k*Z code of Picture 1? Look at the important option `even odd rule`. Do PStricks have the equivalent command, macro,.. as Ti*k*Z?

> **Notice:** I prefer PStricks to Ti*k*Z but sometimes I recognize the Ti*k*Z code is better.

Sorry if I make you being uncomfortable.

Comment: Wonderful package!

Comment: Exactly........................!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A PSTricks solution just for fun!

## Answer 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=blue]
{ 
  \pscircle(1.5;90){3}
  \pscircle(1.5;-30){3} 
  \pscircle(1.5;210){3} 
} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The stroke color is left black just for a trivial reason.

Cartesian coordinates are used in response to the request.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=blue]
{ 
  \pscircle(0,1.5){3}
  \pscircle(1.29,-0.75){3} 
  \pscircle(-1.29,-0.75){3} 
} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

## Answer 2

Non-zero winding rule:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
{
    \pscircle{1}
    \pscircle{2}
}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Non-zero winding rule:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
{
    \psarcn(0,0){1}{360}{0}
    \pscircle{2}
}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even-odd rule:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=t](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red]
{
    \pscircle{1}
    \pscircle{2}
}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Here is an answer based on the one by @Thomas. Differences

- the "elementary" regions I, II, ..., VIII are not numbered the same. My numbering is that "N" is the Roman number of "n+1" where "n" in binary is "abc", and the region is intersection of A or not A with B or not B with C or not C according to a, b, c = 0 or 1. (Boolean logic)
- the macro needs only one input: a TeX formula for the set. Please enrich the syntax by adding suitable definitions converting TeX math macros into Boolean logic notation, as understood by [`xintexpr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xintexpr)
- I have dropped all fancy customization of colors, but xparse virtuosos will add the fancy optional arguments to re-install it if needed.

Thus, the big point here is that `xintexpr` computes automatically from the TeX typesetting formula which regions are to be filled in diagram.

> **attention to `\setminus`** it *must* be used either with parentheses `\setminus (...)` or without but then with only one letter `\setminus A`
>   ok, `\setminus A\cap B` not ok, because the translation here to xintexpr
>   boolean will do naively something equivalent to `and not(A) and B`, not the expected `and not(A and B)`. In short, you must treat `\setminus` as having maximally tying precedence.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xparse,xintexpr}

\def\KOEA{1.9,2.2}
\def\FOEA{1.4,1}

\def\KOEB{3.3,2.2}
\def\FOEB{1.2,1}

\def\KOEC{2.75,1.4}
\def\FOEC{1.4,1}

\def\KOEO{2.5,2}
\def\FOEO{2.5,2.0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisA}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEA)(\FOEA)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEA)(\FOEA)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisB}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEB)(\FOEB)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEB)(\FOEB)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisC}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEC)(\FOEC)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEC)(\FOEC)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisOmega}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEO)(\FOEO)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEO)(\FOEO)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndeEllipsen}{sm}{%
\EreignisOmega%
\pnodes(0.25,3.75){Omega}(0.25,0.25){A}(4.75,3.75){B}(4.75,0.25){C}(2.5,-0.5){E}
\pnodes(0.7,3.36){MOmega}(0.85,1.55){MA}(4,3){MB}(3.8,0.75){MC}
\EreignisA
\EreignisB
\EreignisC
\rput[t](E){#2}%
\IfBooleanF{#1}{%
\rput(Omega){$\Omega$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](Omega)(MOmega)
\rput(A){$A$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](A)(MA)
\rput(B){$B$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](B)(MB)
\rput(C){$C$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.2](C)(MC)
}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeclip}{m}{%
\pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
 \code{/clip /eoclip load def}%
  \psframe(-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
  #1
  }%
}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
% We could use some automated macro creation but well
% 000
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisOmega*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}%
% 001
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 010
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 011
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
}%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 100
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 101
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 110
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
% 111
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
%\ExplSyntaxOff

%\xintverbosetrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\VennFromTeX[1]{%
    \VennFromTeX@main #1%
}%
\def\VennFromTeX@main$#1${%
    \begingroup
        \xintglobaldefstrue
        \def\overline##1{!(##1)}% or not(##1)
        \def\cap{&&}% or 'and'
        \def\cup{||}% or 'or'
        \def\oplus{ 'xor' }%
        \def\setminus##1{\ifx(##1&&!(\else &&!(##1)\fi}%
        \let\bigl\empty
        \let\bigr\empty
        % ....
        % (add above all needed extra definitions: \let\Bigl\empty etc...) 
    \xintdeffunc MyBool(A, B, C) := #1;% #1 must use A, B, C only
    \endgroup
    % we could make a loop here (using \@Roman), but let's stay simple
    % I trust xparse experts can wrap this up in macros allowing to customize
    % the colors
% ATTENTION THAT THESE \arealI...VIII ARE NOT THE SAME AS IN @THOMAS ANSWER
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(0, 0, 0)}{\arealI[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(0, 0, 1)}{\arealII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(0, 1, 0)}{\arealIII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(0, 1, 1)}{\arealIV[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(1, 0, 0)}{\arealV[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(1, 0, 1)}{\arealVI[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(1, 1, 0)}{\arealVII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(1, 1, 1)}{\arealVIII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \EndeEllipsen{$#1$}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%testing if I, II, ..., VIII are as expected
% \makeatletter
% \xintFor*#1in{\xintSeq{0}{7}}\do{%
% \begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
% \rput(2,0){\the\numexpr1+#1}
% \@nameuse{areal\@Roman{\numexpr1+#1}}[cyan][0.8]
% \EndeEllipsen{}
% \end{pspicture}
% }%
% \end{document}


\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$A\cap B\cap C$}%
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$A\cap (B\cup C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cup C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$\overline{A}\setminus (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$(\overline{A}\setminus B)\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$\bigl((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\bigr)\setminus(A\cap B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennFromTeX{$A\oplus B\oplus C$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

---

Here is code to generate all 256 Venn diagrams. Just insert it in body of above document and don't forget to add `\usepackage{xintbinhex}` to preamble.

```
% generating all graphics

% 0<= n <= 255 has eight binary digits
% abcdefgh
% a=1 -> region VIII is included (A cap B cap C)
% b=1 -> region VII is included
% ...
% h=1 -> region I is included (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C})
% We want also to describe the region as a formula...
% We could use 8 \xintFor loops #1, ..., #8, but then
% we still need to convert #1*7 to binary, #2*6, #3*5 etc...
% I thus use xintbinhex per convenience but \ifodd would be enough
% As I use xintbinhex, I also use a single \xintFor* loop

%\def\gobbleone#1{}%
\def\gobbletwo#1#2{}%
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{0}{255}}:
{%
   \xintDigitsOf\xintDecToBin{\the\numexpr256+#1\relax}\to\Regions
   % due to leading 1 there will be a shift of indexing in \Regions
   \edef\x{\xintifboolexpr{\Regions{\the\numexpr9-0}}% 000
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup
                           \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\cap\overline{C}}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-1}}%  001
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\cap C}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-2}}%  010
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup \overline{A}\cap B \cap\overline{C}}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-3}}% 011
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup \overline{A} \cap B \cap C}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-4}}% 100
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-5}}% 101
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup A\cap \overline{B}\cap C}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-6}}% 110
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup A\cap B\cap \overline{C}}}%
              {}%
           \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-7}}% 111
              {\unexpanded{\allowbreak\cup A\cap B \cap C}}%
              {}%
    }%
   \xintifForFirst{\def\x{\emptyset}}
                  {\oodef\x{\expandafter\gobbletwo\x}}%
   \begin{pspicture}(0,-2)(5,4)
   % I will leave here each Region as individual call, so a color can
   % be added by modifying this code
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-0}}{\arealI[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-1}}{\arealII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-2}}{\arealIII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-3}}{\arealIV[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-4}}{\arealV[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-5}}{\arealVI[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-6}}{\arealVII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \xintifboolexpr{\Regions{9-7}}{\arealVIII[cyan][0.8]}{}%
    \EndeEllipsen{\parbox{4cm}{\centering$\x$}}%
   \end{pspicture}%
}%
```

Defect: the description of the set is as a disjoint union of atomic events. There might be some canonical shorter description but I never really thought about it. For example one of those diagram will represent $\Omega\setminus A$ but this not the way it will be legended.

Here is how this example comes out (on page 16 of document with nothing else, i.e. it corresponds to #1 = 15 in the loop, 15=1111 means to keep atomic events 0=000, 1=001, 2=010, 3=011, which is complement of A in Omega.

[image]

---

---

Here is now with **4 sets**.

This time, with TikZ code (I know neither PSTricks nor TikZ and can only survive from copying pre-existing drawing instructions; in this case I started from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100091/4686 by @JohnHammersley in 2013).

First I include an image of all atomic events, which are the regions to which the `\Atomic...` macros in code next refer. (this was done for checking while preparing answer)

[image]

Here is the code for  `\VennFromTeX`,  use it as `\VennFromTeX{$ set formula with A, B, C, D $}`. Same instructions as above for three sets.
(one may wish to enlarge the syntax for example by allowing use of `U` or `\Omega` and defining it in xintexpr to be simply `1`, and similarly `\emptyset` could be defined to be `0`).

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{xintexpr}% for \VennFromTeX


% For drawing
\def\firstellip{(-1.6, 0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\secondellip{(-0.3, 1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\thirdellip{(0.3, 1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
\def\fourthellip{(1.6, 0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}

\def\bounding{(-5,-3) rectangle (5,4)}

% Elementary sets
% ABCD
% abcd a, b, c, d in {0, 1}
\def\Atomic{% 0000
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% exterior
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \bounding;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomici{% 0001
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% fourth ellipse corner
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \fourthellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicii{% 0010
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% third ellipse corner
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \thirdellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomiciii{% 0011
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \thirdellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomiciv{% 0100
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% second ellipse corner
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \secondellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicv{% 0101
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \secondellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicvi{% 0110
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \secondellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicvii{% 0111
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \firstellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \secondellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicviii{% 1000
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicix{% 1001
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicx{% 1010
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicxi{% 1011
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicxii{% 1100
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip;
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicxiii{% 1101
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip;
            \clip \thirdellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicxiv{% 1110
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip;
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%
\def\Atomicxv{% 1111
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]%
            \clip \secondellip;
            \clip \thirdellip;
            \clip \fourthellip;
        \fill[yellow] \firstellip;
        \end{scope}
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\VennFromTeX[1]{\VennFromTeX@main #1}%

\def\VennFromTeX@main$#1${%
    \begingroup
        \xintglobaldefstrue
        \def\overline##1{!(##1)}% or not(##1)
        \def\cap{&&}% or 'and'
        \def\cup{||}% or 'or'
        \def\oplus{ 'xor' }%
        \def\setminus##1{\ifx(##1&&!(\else &&!(##1)\fi}%
        \let\bigl\empty
        \let\bigr\empty
        % ....
        % (add above all needed extra definitions: \let\Bigl\empty etc...) 
    \xintdeffunc MyBool(A, B, C, D) := #1;% #1 must use A, B, C, Donly
    \endgroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \xintFor* ##1 in {01}:
    {%
      \xintFor* ##2 in {01}:
      {%
        \xintFor* ##3 in {01}:
        {%
          \xintFor* ##4 in {01}:
          {%
             \xintifboolexpr{MyBool(##1, ##2, ##3, ##4)}
             {\csname
               Atomic\romannumeral\numexpr##1*8+##2*4+##3*2+##4\endcsname}%
             {}%
           }%
         }%
       }%
    }%
    \draw \bounding;

    % \fill[white] \firstellip;
    % \fill[white] \secondellip;
    % \fill[white] \thirdellip;
    % \fill[white] \fourthellip;

    \draw \firstellip node [label={[xshift=-2cm, yshift=-0.9cm]$A$}] {};
    \draw \secondellip node [label={[xshift=-2.1cm, yshift=2.1cm]$B$}] {};
    \draw \thirdellip node [label={[xshift=2.1cm, yshift=2.1cm]$C$}] {};
    \draw \fourthellip node [label={[xshift=2cm, yshift=-0.9cm]$D$}] {};

    \draw \bounding node [label=below left:$U$] {};

    \draw (0, 0) node [yshift=+4.4cm] {$#1$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% \xintverbosetrue

\VennFromTeX{$A\cap B\cap C\cap D$}

\VennFromTeX{$(A\cap B)\cup (C\cap D)$}

\VennFromTeX{$(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\cap(\overline{C}\cup\overline{D})$}

% attention to use parentheses for disambiguating \setminus 

\VennFromTeX{$(A\cup B \cup C) \setminus(B\cup C\cup D)$}

\VennFromTeX{$(A\cup B \cup C) \cap (B\cup C\cup D)$}

\VennFromTeX{$((A\setminus (B\cup C\cup D)) \cup B\cap C\cap
  D)\setminus (A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$}

\end{document}
```

Be careful to read the caveat top regarding usage of `\setminus` in input.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and finally

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your answer!

Comment: (+1) Wow, fantastic!

Comment: Encyclopedic answer

Comment: careful in first part of answer when inputting a long formula that it some parts may be cut off the page, check the `\parbox` in second part how to work around that, and I also increased the vertical dimension.

Comment: It will grant you a bounty of 500 if you do the same thing for at least 4 sets. Note that using circles is impossible.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity wow, 500! wait a minute... what is the task with 4 sets: generating all diagrams or one diagram for arbitrary formula with A, B, C, D ? (I see some possibilities for design at  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#/media/File:Venn4.svg)). Regarding xintexpr, I can go with no difficulty up to 9 sets...

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I have to get dinner but just give me time to learn PSTricks and I can do with 4 sets afterwards...

Comment: Objective: let user choose any region in at least 4 sets. Thanks!

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity done for 4 sets, with TikZ. Based upon https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100091/4686 for the TikZ code.

Comment: all `(-5,-5)` in the code for `4-Venn` should be `(-5,-4)`, I copied them over from linked answer but noticed only later the white margin at bottom of pictures.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity You should ask the OP (chishimotoji  ) to accept jbfu's answer so that it appears first in the results.

Comment: @AndréC: The bounty has nothing to do with the current accepted.

Comment: If  @ArtificialStupidity suggest accepting jbfu's answer ,willingly. (hehe)

Comment: I think the answer of @ArtificialStupidity addressed exactly the precise question. I came late to the game and answered another question. So please keep green tick to ArtificialStupidity whose generous bounty will reward amply enough my answer...

Comment: `\VennFromTeX` should arguably admit an optional argument, in case the parsing of the TeX formula would cause problems (e.g. one wants `\mathbf{A}`). This would be the human translation of the set formula using xintexpr syntax as function of variables A, B, C, D: `&&` for logical and, `||` for logical or, `'xor'` for logical xor (the ⊕ here), ``not(...)`` or ``!(...)`` for complement...``0`` for empty set and ``1`` for the universe. One can also use syntax `all(A, B, C)` for `A 'and' B 'and' C`(`A&&B&&C`) and `any(A, B, C)` for the ``'or'`` and `xor(A, B, C)` in place of `A 'xor' B 'xor' C`.

Comment: All that remains is to vote for jbfu's answer so that it can be positioned as the second answer!

Comment: You should write a package.

Comment: `jbfu` have left this site for good.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=blue,linecolor=blue]{% 
    \pscircle(1.5;90){3}
    \pscircle(1.5;-30){3} 
    \pscircle(1.5;210){3} 
} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other simple example:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-3.2)(3.2,3.2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40](0,0){3}
  \psclip{\pscircle(-1,0.5){1.5}% these object(s) will clip
          \pscircle(1,0.5){1.5}}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](0,-1){1.5}% from this object
  \endpsclip
  \pscircle(-1,0.5){1.5}% to get the clipped circle lines
  \pscircle(0,-1){1.5}
  \pscircle(1,0.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-3.2)(3.2,3.2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40](0,0){3}
  \psclip{\pscircle(-1,0.5){1.5}}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](0,-1){1.5}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](1,0.5){1.5}
  \endpsclip
  \pscircle(-1,0.5){1.5}
  \pscircle(0,-1){1.5}
  \pscircle(1,0.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-3.2)(3.2,3.2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40](0,0){3}
  \psclip{\pscircle(0,-1){1.5}}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](-1,0.5){1.5}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](1,0.5){1.5}
  \endpsclip
  \pscircle(-1,0.5){1.5}
  \pscircle(0,-1){1.5}
  \pscircle(1,0.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.2,-3.2)(3.2,3.2)
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40](0,0){3}
  \psclip{\pscircle(0,-1){1.5}}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](1,0.5){1.5}
  \endpsclip
  \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40](-1,0.5){1.5}
  \pscircle(0,-1){1.5}
  \pscircle(1,0.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't known that there is a option as " fillstyle=eofill " before. It doesn't within PStrick User's Guide.

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Box/boxfill#2

Comment: I am really impressived by your code.  Only with \psclip,\pscustom, you created some the interesting result. I have deleted more three comments before. May be my knowledge about **\psclip** is not enough to generate several thing which I want. :((((

Comment: clipping is nothing else than taking a knife let it go along a circle or two corcles and cut everything from a given cake. `\psclip{the way of the knife} ... the cake .. \endpsclip`

Answer (score 10):

A TikZ solution for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[even odd rule,fill=blue](0,0)circle(3)(4,0)circle(3)(2,3)circle(3);       
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Venn]

### Update: To answer @ArtificialStupidity's comment

Here is a solution with different coordinate points from those of the question asked by the OP. The centres of the circles form an equilateral triangle here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[even odd rule,fill=blue](0,0)circle(3)(3,0)circle(3)(60:3)circle(3);       
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: venn-2]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Yes, as in the figure given as an example by the OP. I didn't change the coordinates.

Comment: +1 for the equilateral triangle Δ

Answer (score 8):

With this definitions every surface can be colored.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xparse,xintexpr}

\def\radiusK{\xinttheiexpr[6] 2*sqrt(3)/3\relax}

\def\KOEA{2.5,2}
\def\FOEA{\radiusK,\radiusK}

\def\KOEB{2,1}
\def\FOEB{\radiusK,\radiusK}

\def\KOEC{3,1}
\def\FOEC{\radiusK,\radiusK}

\def\KOEO{2.5,1.375}
\def\FOEO{2.5,2.5}

%uncomment the following lines to have ellipses
%\def\KOEA{1.9,2.2}
%\def\FOEA{1.4,1}
%
%\def\KOEB{3.3,2.2}
%\def\FOEB{1.2,1}
%
%\def\KOEC{2.75,1.4}
%\def\FOEC{1.4,1}
%
%\def\KOEO{2.5,2}
%\def\FOEO{2.5,2.0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisA}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEA)(\FOEA)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEA)(\FOEA)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisB}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEB)(\FOEB)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEB)(\FOEB)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisC}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEC)(\FOEC)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEC)(\FOEC)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisOmega}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEO)(\FOEO)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEO)(\FOEO)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndeEllipsen}{sm}{%
\EreignisOmega%
\pnodes(0.25,3.75){Omega}(0.25,0.25){A}(4.75,3.75){B}(4.75,0.25){C}(2.5,-0.5){E}
\pnodes(0.7,3.36){MOmega}(0.85,1.55){MA}(4,3){MB}(3.8,0.75){MC}
\EreignisA
\EreignisB
\EreignisC
\rput[t](E){#2}%
\IfBooleanF{#1}{%
\rput(Omega){$\Omega$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](Omega)(MOmega)
\rput(A){$A$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](A)(MA)
\rput(B){$B$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](B)(MB)
\rput(C){$C$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.2](C)(MC)
}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeclip}{m}{%
\pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
 \code{/clip /eoclip load def}%
  \psframe(-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
  #1
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisOmega*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{\EreignisB}
        \psclip{\EreignisC}%
                \EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
        \endpsclip
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\EndeEllipsen*{$A\setminus C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealVI
\EndeEllipsen*{$A\cap B\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealIII
\arealV
\arealVI
\EndeEllipsen*{$A\cap (B\cup C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\EreignisC*%
\EndeEllipsen*{$(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cup C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\arealIV
\arealVIII
\EndeEllipsen*{$\overline{A}\setminus (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealVIII
\EndeEllipsen*{$(\overline{A}\setminus B)\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealII
\arealV
\arealVI
\arealVII
\EndeEllipsen*{$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealIII
\arealV
\EndeEllipsen*{$\bigl((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\bigr)\setminus(A\cap B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you want to check out this.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xparse,xintexpr}

%\def\radiusK{\xinttheiexpr[6] 2*sqrt(3)/3\relax}
%
%\def\KOEA{2.5,2}
%\def\FOEA{\radiusK,\radiusK}
%
%\def\KOEB{2,1}
%\def\FOEB{\radiusK,\radiusK}
%
%\def\KOEC{3,1}
%\def\FOEC{\radiusK,\radiusK}
%
%\def\KOEO{2.5,1.375}
%\def\FOEO{2.5,2.5}

%uncomment the following lines to have ellipses
\def\KOEA{1.9,2.2}
\def\FOEA{1.4,1}

\def\KOEB{3.3,2.2}
\def\FOEB{1.2,1}

\def\KOEC{2.75,1.4}
\def\FOEC{1.4,1}

\def\KOEO{2.5,2}
\def\FOEO{2.5,2.0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisA}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEA)(\FOEA)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEA)(\FOEA)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisB}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEB)(\FOEB)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEB)(\FOEB)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisC}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEC)(\FOEC)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEC)(\FOEC)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisOmega}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEO)(\FOEO)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEO)(\FOEO)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndeEllipsen}{sm}{%
\EreignisOmega%
\pnodes(0.25,3.75){Omega}(0.25,0.25){A}(4.75,3.75){B}(4.75,0.25){C}(2.5,-0.5){E}
\pnodes(0.7,3.36){MOmega}(0.85,1.55){MA}(4,3){MB}(3.8,0.75){MC}
\EreignisA
\EreignisB
\EreignisC
\rput[t](E){#2}%
\IfBooleanF{#1}{%
\rput(Omega){$\Omega$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](Omega)(MOmega)
\rput(A){$A$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](A)(MA)
\rput(B){$B$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](B)(MB)
\rput(C){$C$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.2](C)(MC)
}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeclip}{m}{%
\pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
 \code{/clip /eoclip load def}%
  \psframe(-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
  #1
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisOmega*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{\EreignisB}
        \psclip{\EreignisC}%
                \EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
        \endpsclip
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\EndeEllipsen{$A\setminus C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealVI
\EndeEllipsen{$A\cap B\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealIII
\arealV
\arealVI
\EndeEllipsen{$A\cap (B\cup C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\EreignisC*%
\EndeEllipsen{$(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cup C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\arealIV
\arealVIII
\EndeEllipsen{$\overline{A}\setminus (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealVIII
\EndeEllipsen{$(\overline{A}\setminus B)\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealII
\arealV
\arealVI
\arealVII
\EndeEllipsen{$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealIII
\arealV
\EndeEllipsen{$\bigl((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\bigr)\setminus(A\cap B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of xint-package using xintFor and xintForpair you can write

```
\VennIII{(2,red),(4,cyan),(6,magenta),(8,green)}{Text}%
```

so every surface becomes an own color, or you write

```
\VennIII[blue](0.5){2,4,6,8}{Text}%
```

and all becomes color blue with opacity 0.5.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xparse,xintexpr}

\def\KOEA{1.9,2.2}
\def\FOEA{1.4,1}

\def\KOEB{3.3,2.2}
\def\FOEB{1.2,1}

\def\KOEC{2.75,1.4}
\def\FOEC{1.4,1}

\def\KOEO{2.5,2}
\def\FOEO{2.5,2.0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisA}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEA)(\FOEA)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEA)(\FOEA)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisB}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEB)(\FOEB)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEB)(\FOEB)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisC}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEC)(\FOEC)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEC)(\FOEC)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EreignisOmega}{sO{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#2,opacity=#3](\KOEO)(\FOEO)}{%
\psellipse(\KOEO)(\FOEO)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndeEllipsen}{sm}{%
\EreignisOmega%
\pnodes(0.25,3.75){Omega}(0.25,0.25){A}(4.75,3.75){B}(4.75,0.25){C}(2.5,-0.5){E}
\pnodes(0.7,3.36){MOmega}(0.85,1.55){MA}(4,3){MB}(3.8,0.75){MC}
\EreignisA
\EreignisB
\EreignisC
\rput[t](E){#2}%
\IfBooleanF{#1}{%
\rput(Omega){$\Omega$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](Omega)(MOmega)
\rput(A){$A$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](A)(MA)
\rput(B){$B$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.25](B)(MB)
\rput(C){$C$}\pcline[nodesepA=0.2](C)(MC)
}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeclip}{m}{%
\pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
 \code{/clip /eoclip load def}%
  \psframe(-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
  #1
  }%
}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\arealI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisOmega*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIII}{!O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealIV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisC
}%
}%
\EreignisB*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealV}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVI}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{\EreignisB}%
        \psclip{\EreignisC}%
                \EreignisA*[#1][#2]%
        \endpsclip
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
  \EreignisC
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arealVIII}{O{cyan}!O{0.8}}{%
\psclip{%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisA
  \EreignisB
}%
\codeclip{%
  \EreignisB
}%
}%
\EreignisC*[#1][#2]%
\endpsclip
}
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\VIIIarea}{O{cyan}O{0.8}m}{%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=1}{\arealI[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=2}{\arealII[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=3}{\arealIII[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=4}{\arealIV[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=5}{\arealV[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=6}{\arealVI[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=7}{\arealVII[#1][#2]}{}%
\xintifboolexpr{#3=8}{\arealVIII[#1][#2]}{}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\VennIII}{oD(){0.8}m!g}{%
\IfValueTF{#1}%
    {%
        \xintFor ##1 in {#3}\do {\VIIIarea[#1][#2]{##1}}%
    }%
    {%
        \xintForpair ##1##2 in {#3}\do {\VIIIarea[##2][#2]{##1}}%
    }%
\EndeEllipsen{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII{(2,red),(4,cyan),(6,magenta),(8,green)}{Text}%
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[orange]{6}{$A\cap B\cap C$}%
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[cyan]{3,5,6}{$A\cap (B\cup C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[magenta](0.5){1,5,6,7}{$(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cup C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[green](0.2){1,4,8}{$\overline{A}\setminus (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[cyan]{8}{$(\overline{A}\setminus B)\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII(1){(2,cyan),(5,orange),(6,green),(7,magenta)}{$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,4)
\VennIII[cyan]{3,5}{$\bigl((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\bigr)\setminus(A\cap B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey bro, is there a shorter way? Your code seem being enormously complex.

Comment: This is because I first create all sorts of single surfaces by clipping. Then you can get any desired combination by fading in this area. This is a bit dull, but much easier to use. For example for area 2, area 4 and area 8you can use

\begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](0,-1)(5,4)
\arealI
\arealIV
\arealVIII
\EndeEllipsen{$\overline{A}\setminus (B\cap C)$}
\end{pspicture}