# Different colors in the intersection of a venn diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am currently trying to change the color of the intersection between two circles in a venn diagram. I have tried different proposed solution here on stack without success. The code I am running is the following;

```
\begin{center}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=0.5]
    \fill[green] \firstcircle;
    \fill[green] \secondcircle;
    \fill[red] \thirdcircle;
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67395/86 and its answers.  You may be able to adapt one of those to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill opacity=.5` already fills all intersections with different colors. But if this is not enough for you and prefer to select the color for every intersection, you can use following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=1]
    \fill[green] \firstcircle node[black] {$A$};
    \fill[blue] \secondcircle node[black] {$B$};
    \fill[red] \thirdcircle node[black] {$C$};
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[brown] \secondcircle;
        \fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \fill[orange] \thirdcircle;
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[pink] \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) version to provide some diversion while you are waiting for the TikZ mountain rescue team.  Compile with `lualatex` for the `mplib` support (or work out how to adapt it for [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en)).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path C[];
    C1 = fullcircle rotated -60 scaled 3cm;
    C2 = C1 shifted (2cm, 0);
    C3 = C2 rotated 60;

    path r[];

    r1 = buildcycle(C1, C2);
    r2 = buildcycle(C2, C3);
    r3 = buildcycle(C3, C1);
    r4 = buildcycle(C1, C2, C3);

    fill C1 withcolor 3/4[red, white];
    fill C2 withcolor 3/4[green, white];
    fill C3 withcolor 3/4[blue, white];

    fill r1 withcolor 3/4[red+green,white];
    fill r2 withcolor 3/4[green+blue,white];
    fill r3 withcolor 3/4[blue+red,white];
    fill r4 withcolor 3/4[red+green+blue, white];

    draw C1;  label("A", center C1);
    draw C2;  label("B", center C2);
    draw C3;  label("C", center C3);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

NB: the `rotated -60` on the definition of C1 is important.  It stops the `point 0` of each circle being contained in the others.  This is necessary to avoid a feature of `buildcycle`.