# How can I draw a rectangle around venn Diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box, venn-diagrams

I have tried some of the solutions to similar questions, but none of them included minipages, which seems to be the problem (I`m fairly new to LaTeX)

So, here's the coding:

```
% Definition of circles
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{black!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{grey!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

% Set A or B
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.48\textwidth}
    \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                  \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M$};
\end{minipage}
\end{tikzpicture}
% Set A and B
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$A$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M$};
    \node[anchor=west] at (current bounding box.east) {$A \cap B$}
\end{minipage}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: What it looks like]

Also, if you know how to put the "B" in the center of the circle on the right I`d appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: You should not use `minipage` inside Ti*k*Z pictures

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to TeX.SE! It is good that you included your code. In terms of drawing a rectangle around the venn diagram, you could import the `fit` library from Ti*k*z using `\usetikzlibrary{fit}`. I have completed an example to illustrate. Also, I have changed the code a little bit. You now have one `tikzpicture` (with no minipage). The first venn diagram has its own scope and the second has its own as well. I have changed the placement of `M` so that it would be easier to read. There are two types overall in terms of appearance, you choose the one you like.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,color}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Definition of circles
    \def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
    \def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
    %
    \colorlet{circle edge}{black!50}
    \colorlet{circle area}{gray!20}
    %
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box = orScope]
    \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                  \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (orScope.north){$M$};
    \node[anchor=north] at (orScope.south) {$A \cup B$};
    \end{scope}
    \node[fit=(orScope), draw] {};% The frame around the scope
    %
    \begin{scope}[xshift = 7cm,local bounding box = andScope]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$A$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (andScope.north) {$M$};
    \node[anchor=west] at (andScope.south east) {$A \cap B$};
    \end{scope}
    \node[fit=(andScope), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to complete this part of my project thanks to  your help!

Answer (score 4):

There are dedicated packages for that. Assuming you do not want to use any of those, I'd like to advertize [some styles that help you drawing these diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482038/121799). These are `not inside`, `inside` to specify the sets and `frame` for drawing a frame around these pictures. Your first picture is easy, you only need to fill the circles. The second one can be achieved with

```
\pgfkeys{inside/.list={\pathA,\pathB},shade=gray}
```

and the frames can be done with

```
\draw[frame=5pt];
```

where `5pt` indicates the margin.

Here are code and result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
(current bounding box.north east)} }, 
use path/.code={\pgfsetpath#1},%learned from Kpym
frame/.style={insert path={
([xshift=-#1,yshift=-#1]current bounding box.south west) rectangle
([xshift=#1,yshift=#1]current bounding box.north east)}}
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{not inside/.code={\clip[use path=#1,reverseclip];},
inside/.code={\clip[use path=#1];},
shade/.code=\fill[#1] (current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
(current bounding box.north east);}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,fill=gray] (-1,0) node{$A$} circle [radius=1.5cm]
(1,0) node{$B$} circle[radius=1.5cm] (0,1.5) node[above]{$M$}
(0,-1.5) node[below]{$A\cup B$};
\draw[frame=5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}~%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,save path=\pathA] (-1,0) node{$A$} circle [radius=1.5cm];
\draw[thick,save path=\pathB] (1,0) node{$B$} circle[radius=1.5cm];
\path (0,1.5) node[above]{$M$}
(0,-1.5) node[below]{$A\cap B$};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\pgfkeys{inside/.list={\pathA,\pathB},shade=gray}
\end{scope}
\draw[frame=5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I now have a bigger understanding of those commands and maybe will be able to draw some myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

If you really wants to use `minipage`, you have to put the environment outside `tikzpicture`. Literally `minipage` does nothing for you here, but it does many things *against* you.

However, for figures side-by-side, a `subfigure` environment (from `subcaption`) is better in this case.

And, to draw a rectangle, you can use the special node `current bounding box`, with some shifts if needed.

Btw your diagrams are too wide for the normal margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Definition of circles
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{black!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{gray!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                  \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$A$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M$};
    \node[anchor=west] at (current bounding box.east) {$A \cap B$};
    \draw ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}]current bounding box.north west) rectangle
          ([shift={(1ex,-1ex)}]current bounding box.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]