# drawing "trifecta" color mixing set

Tags: color, circles, overlap

I want to illustrate overlaps in three sets, similar to how one of these standard color plots [do they have a name?] look like

[image: three-color-set]

except that I want to choose my own colors and different text [not C, M, and Y].  (I want the inside most quasi-triangle to be a red, the area outside of the plot to be a green, and the partials [both three inner and three outers, though different] have some sort of mix colors.  presumably a little bit lighter, because I need text in each intersection, too, that needs to be readable.). the idea is to show that when all three things come together, it's bad.  a trifecta.

maybe I need a graphical artist rather than latex...or is this somehow built in?

Comment: Have a look at tikz. You can use `\clip` to draw parts of circles, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67429/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9682/36296

Comment: If you think a moment about how to position the three circles, it should not be too difficult to come up with something using `arc`s and polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to draw the single segments directly using polar coordinates and some `arc`s. There is no need to calculate intersections in a complicated manner. This way, you can style each segment as you wish. I leave it to you to place the nodes for the labels:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % upper circle segment
    \path[fill=red!50] (180:1) 
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=60, end angle=120, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=60, end angle=120, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % lower left circle segment
    \path[fill=blue!50] (180:1) 
        arc[start angle=120, end angle=300, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=240, end angle=180, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=240, end angle=180, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % lower right circle
    \path[fill=green!50] (0:1) 
        arc[start angle=420, end angle=240, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=300, end angle=360, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=300, end angle=360, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % inner pseudo triangle
    \path[fill=gray!10] (0:0) 
        arc[start angle=60, end angle=0, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=300, end angle=240, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=120, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % upper left pseudo triangle
    \path[fill=magenta!50] (0:0) 
        arc[start angle=60, end angle=120, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=240, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=120, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % upper right pseudo triangle
    \path[fill=yellow!50] (0:0) 
        arc[start angle=120, end angle=60, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=360, end angle=300, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=60, radius=1]
        -- cycle;

    % lower pseudo triangle
    \path[fill=cyan!50, draw, thick] (240:1) 
        arc[start angle=240, end angle=300, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=360, end angle=300, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=240, end angle=180, radius=1]
        -- cycle;
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am always amazed by the imagination of the creators and users of latex...

Comment: Is it easy to enter text in the center of each of these segments?

Comment: @ivoWelch You can just place some nodes, for example using `\begin{scope}[shift={(270:0.5)}] \node at (90:1) {A}; \node at (210:1) {B}; \node at (330:1) {C}; \node at (30:0.75) {D}; \node at (150:0.75) {E}; \node at (270:0.75) {F}; \node at (0:0) {G}; \end{scope}`.